# compare string got error ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to use `if` condition to update some values in a column using the following code:

```
if df['COLOR_DESC'] == 'DARK BLUE':
    df['NEW_COLOR_DESC'] = 'BLUE'
```

But I got the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

So what is wrong with this piece of code?

Comment: @Dadep. Please refrain from putting extra spaces before punctuation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your immediate question, the problem is that the expression `df['COLOR_DESC'] == 'DARK BLUE'` results in a Series of booleans. The error message is telling you that there is no one unambiguous way to convert that array to a single boolean value as `if` demands.

The solution is actually not to use `if`, since you are not applying the `if` to each element that is `DARK_BLUE`. Use the boolean values directly as a mask instead:

```
rows = (df['COLOR_DESC'] == 'DARK BLUE')
df.loc[rows, 'COLOR_DESC'] = 'BLUE'
```

You have to use `loc` to update the original `df` because if you index it as `df[rows]['COLOR_DESC']`, you will be getting a copy of the required subset. Setting the values in the copy will *not* propagate back to the original, and you will even get a warning about that.

For example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data={'COLOR_DESC': ['LIGHT_RED', 'DARK_BLUE', 'MEDUIM_GREEN', 'DARK_BLUE']})
>>> df
     COLOR_DESC
0     LIGHT_RED
1     DARK_BLUE
2  MEDUIM_GREEN
3     DARK_BLUE

>>> rows = (df['COLOR_DESC'] == 'DARK BLUE')
>>> rows
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
Name: COLOR_DESC, dtype: bool

>>> df.loc[rows, 'COLOR_DESC'] = 'BLUE'
>>> df
     COLOR_DESC
0     LIGHT_RED
1          BLUE
2  MEDUIM_GREEN
3          BLUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `.loc` slicing like this instead:

```
df['NEW_COLOR_DESC'] = df['COLOR_DESC']
df.loc[df['COLOR_DESC'] == 'DARK BLUE', 'NEW_COLOR_DESC'] = 'BLUE'
```

The reason your solution does not work is because each row of your dataframe will have a different truth value (True/False) based on whether that row contains the value 'DARK BLUE'. The `.loc` function allows you to select only the rows the fit a certain conditional (`df['COLOR_DESC'] == 'DARK BLUE'`) and adjust the value in the column defined ('NEW_COLOR_DESC') to the new value ('BLUE')

Answer (score 0):

a series is an array.  What you are asking is akin to:

```
array([1, 2, 3]) == 1
```

Their values are of course not equal, but in numpy (the basis of pandas) the convention is to use boolean operators on arrays elementwise.  The correct way would be:

```
array([1, 2, 3]) == array([1, 2, 4])
```

gives:

```
array([True, True, False])
```

or

```
all(array([1, 2, 3]) == array([1, 2, 4]))
```

gives:

```
False
```

** note, this is how numpy arrays specifically work, not python iterables in general

Comment: How to fix for pandas?

Comment: good question, I don't know.  The specific question was "what's wrong with this piece of code."  Practically speaking it would be better to post information about the right answer, but fundamentally this is what is wrong with the code no?

Comment: Sure. You may want to mention that that is not how native lists work.